# How to override lib/spree/search/base.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree, acts-as-taggable-on

I need to override the `get_products_conditions_for` method in this class, what's the best way of doing this?

I've tried adding this to an initializer:

```
Spree::Search::Base.class_eval do
    def get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
      base_scope.like_any([:name, :description], query.split) | base_scope.joins("JOIN taggings on taggings.taggable_id = spree_products.id JOIN tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id").where("tags.name = ?", query.split)
    end
end
```

which results in this error when starting the server: `uninitialized constant Spree::Search (NameError)`

I've also tried adding this to "/lib/spree/search/base.rb" and "/lib/spree/search/tags_search.rb"

```
module Spree::Search
  class TagsSearch < Spree::Search::Base

    def get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
      base_scope.like_any([:name, :description], query.split) | base_scope.joins("JOIN taggings on taggings.taggable_id = spree_products.id JOIN tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id").where("tags.name = ?", query.split)
    end

  end
end
```

and then `Spree::Config.searcher = TagsSearch` in application.rb...

I've even tried completely replacing the file by placing a replica in the same directory structure within the app, either nothing happens, or I get the mentioned errors...

What I'm trying to do is integrate `acts_as_taggable_on` which is done and working, however the search obviously does not return results from these tags...

**EDIT:** Ok so after Steph's answer I've tried:

```
module Spree::Search
  class TagsSearch < Spree::Search::Base

    def get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
      base_scope.like_any([:name, :description], query.split) | base_scope.joins("JOIN taggings on taggings.taggable_id = spree_products.id JOIN tags on tags.id = taggings.tag_id").where("tags.name = ?", query.split)
    end

  end
end
```

in `app/models/search/tags_search.rb` and Steph's code suggestion in `lib/spree/search/tags_search.rb`

and this:

```
config.to_prepare do
    Spree::Core::Search::Base.send(:include, TagsSearch)
  end
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`

which results in the following when starting the server:

`uninitialized constant TagsSearch (NameError)`

Comment: How do you have spree installed? gem? plugin? Sounds like the load order of spree is the problem.

Comment: As a gem, don't think it comes as anything else...

Answer (score 3):

> I need to override the get_products_conditions_for method in this class, what's the best way of doing this?

In this particular case, I inherited the class and overrode the required method.

As in Spree 3,

1. In config/initializers/spree.rb, Spree.config block `config.searcher_class= Spree::MySearch`
2. Create a file  lib/spree/my_search.rb with the following content:

   ```
   module Spree
     class MySearch < Spree::Core::Search::Base
       def method_to_be_overridden
         # Your new definition here
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   *Note: The above is the prescribed way to alter searcher class in Spree*

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/), which might look something like this:

```
module YourAwesomeModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    alias :spree_get_products_conditions_for :get_products_conditions_for
    def get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
      custom_get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def custom_get_products_conditions_for(base_scope, query)
      #your stuff
    end 
  end
end

Spree::Core::Search::Base.send(:include, YourAwesomeModule)
```

This is doing a couple of things:

- Using ActiveSupport::Concern is a nice/clean way to extend class and instance methods for a give class.
- Alias preserves the Spree method. You don't have to do this bit if you don't want to.

While in development, because default config settings result in non-caching classes but not reloading lib/ modules, you might need to add this inside config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Spree::Core::Search::Base.send(:include, YourAwesomeModule)
end
```

Comment: Try removing the namespace and inheritance on TagSearch. It doesn't have to belong in the Spree::Search namespace, nor does it need to inherit from Spree::Search::Base. In my example, Rails.root/lib/your_awesome_module.rb would contain the module I described. And you still need to include the ActiveSupport::concern and included bits.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have your code in lib/awesome_search.rb and the config.to_prepare block in config/environments/development.rb, and am still getting similar errors: "uninitialized constant AwesomeSearch (NameError)"

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to make a note that I too was trying to do something similar and getting the "Uninitialized constant" error for my module when setting searcher_class in my spree initializer. I had my search module in Spree::Core::Search and it worked when I used config.searcher_class = Spree::Core::Search::MySearch.